# How to add .json file into PHP for country code

Tags: php, json

I have installed one private app in my shopify store to get a required details as .csv format by using **PHP**

Now i get the country name is INDIA(Example), I want to get IN.

So i ihave a .json file which contain all over country code.

Can anyone help me how to include my php file?

This is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/shopify.php';
//require_once 'csv.php';
$t  = "bac2486aa2b31aa5aed1fdd62e77a4ae";
$sc = new ShopifyClient("mine-329.myshopify.com/", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);
if (!isset($t)) {
    if (!isset($_GET['signature'])) {
        $url = $sc->getAuthorizeUrl("read_orders");
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $accTok = $sc->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        echo "token = " . $accTok;
        exit;
        $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
            'published_status' => 'published'
        ));
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            echo $order['id'];
            echo $order['email'];
        }
    }
}
if (isset($t)) {
    $orders               = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
        'published_status' => 'published'
    ));
    $myarray              = array();
    $list[]               = array(
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Financial status',
        'Paid at',
        'Fullfillment Status',
        'Fullfilled at',
        'Accepts Marketing',
        'Currency',
        'Subtotal',
        'Shipping',
        'Taxes',
        'Total',
        'Discount code',
        'Discount Amount',
        'Shipping Method',
        'created at',
        'Lineitem quantity',
        'Lineitem name',
        'Lineitem price',
        'compare at price',
        'Lineitem sku',
        'Lineitem requires shipping',
        'Lineitem taxable',
        'Lineitem fulfillment status',
        'Billing Name',
        'Billing Street',
        'Billing Address1',
        'Billing Address2',
        'Billing Company',
        'Billing City',
        'Billing Zip',
        'Billing Province',
        'Billing Country',
        'Billing Phone',
        'Shipping Name',
        'Shipping Street',
        'Shipping Address1',
        'Shipping Address2',
        'Shipping Company',
        'Shipping City',
        'Shipping Zip',
        'Shipping Province',
        'Shipping Country',
        'Shipping Phone',
        'Notes',
        'Note_attributes',
        'VAT',
        'Cancelled at',
        'Payment Method',
        'Payment Reference',
        'Refund',
        'Vendor',
        'Id',
        'Tags'
    );
    $list                 = array_filter($list);
    $empty_note_attribute = "";
    if (empty($order['note_attributes'])) {
        $empty_note_attribute = "";
    } else {
        $empty_note_attribute = $order['note_attributes'];
    }
    $empty_discount_codes = "";
    if (empty($order['discount_codes'])) {
        $empty_discount_codes = "";
    } else {
        $empty_discount_codes = $order['discount_codes'];
    }

    foreach ($orders as $order) {

        $orders_lineitem = $order['line_items'];
        $lineitemcount   = 0;
        foreach ($orders_lineitem as $lineitem) {
            /*
            Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfill_status = "";
            if (empty($order['fulfillment_status'])) {
                $fulfill_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfill_status = $order['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            /*
            Lineitem Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfillment_status = '';
            if (empty($order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'])) {
                $fulfillment_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfillment_status = $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            $variants          = "";
            $variants          = $sc->call('GET', "admin/variants/" . $lineitem['variant_id'] . ".json", array(
                'published_status' => 'published'
            ));
            $requires_shipping = "false";
            if ($lineitem['requires_shipping']) {
                $requires_shipping = "true";
            }
            $lineitem_taxable = "false";
            if ($lineitem['taxable']) {
                $lineitem_taxable = "true";
            }
            //** Accepts Marketting **

            $accepts_marketting = "no";
            if ($order['buyer_accepts_marketing']) {
                $accepts_marketting = "yes";
            }
            $shipping = '';
            if (count($order['shipping_lines']) > 0) {
                $shipping = $order['shipping_lines'][0]['price'];
            }
            /* 
            Fulfilled at
            */
            $created_at = '';
            if (count($order['fulfillments']) > 0) {
                $created_at = $order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'];
            }
            /*  
            Refunded Amount 
            */
            $refund_price = '';
            if (count($order['refunds']) > 0) {
                foreach ($order['refunds'] as $refund) {
                    $refund_price += $refund['transactions'][0]['receipt']['paid_amount'];
                }
            }
            if ('pending' == $fulfill_status || 'partial' == $fulfill_status) {
                $created_at = '';
            }


            if ($lineitemcount == 0) {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    $order['financial_status'],
                    (($order['financial_status'] != 'partially_refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'authorized')? $order['created_at'] : null),
                    $fulfill_status,
                    $created_at,
                    $accepts_marketting,
                    $order['currency'],
                    $order['subtotal_price'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $shipping : 0),
                    $order['total_tax'],
                    $order['total_price'],
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    $order['total_discounts'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_lines'][0]['code'] : null),
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $fulfillment_status,
                    $order['billing_address']['name'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address2'],
                    $order['billing_address']['company'],
                    $order['billing_address']['city'],
                    $order['billing_address']['zip'],
                    $order['billing_address']['province'],
                    $order['billing_address']['country'],
                    $order['billing_address']['phone'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['name'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address2'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['company'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['city'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['zip'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['province'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['country'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['phone'] : null),
                    $order['note'],
                    $empty_note_attribute,
                    (($order['line_items'][0]['tax_lines'][0]['price'] != '0') ? $order['total_tax'] : null),
                    $order['cancelled_at'],
                    $order['payment_details']['credit_card_company'],
                    $order['checkout_id'],
                    (($refund_price > 0) ? $refund_price : 0),
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    $order['id'],
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            } else {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    '',
                    '',
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    '',
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            }
            $lineitemcount++;
        }
    }
    $order  = $_GET;
    $list[] = array_to_csv_download($myarray, // this array is going to be the second row
        "numbers.csv");
    $list   = array_filter($list);
    array_to_csv_download($list);
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
}
function array_to_csv_download($list)
{
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
        //print_r($row); die;
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

This is part of my all.json :

```
[{"name":"Afghanistan","alpha-2":"AF","alpha-3":"AFG","country-code":"004","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AF","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"034"},{"name":"Åland Islands","alpha-2":"AX","alpha-3":"ALA","country-code":"248","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AX","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Albania","alpha-2":"AL","alpha-3":"ALB","country-code":"008","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AL","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Algeria","alpha-2":"DZ","alpha-3":"DZA","country-code":"012","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:DZ","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"015"},{"name":"American Samoa","alpha-2":"AS","alpha-3":"ASM","country-code":"016","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AS","region-code":"009","sub-region-code":"061"},{"name":"Andorra","alpha-2":"AD","alpha-3":"AND","country-code":"020","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AD","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Angola","alpha-2":"AO","alpha-3":"AGO","country-code":"024","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AO","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Anguilla","alpha-2":"AI","alpha-3":"AIA","country-code":"660","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AI","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Antarctica","alpha-2":"AQ","alpha-3":"ATA","country-code":"010","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AQ"},{"name":"Antigua and Barbuda","alpha-2":"AG","alpha-3":"ATG","country-code":"028","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AG","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Argentina","alpha-2":"AR","alpha-3":"ARG","country-code":"032","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AR","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"Armenia","alpha-2":"AM","alpha-3":"ARM","country-code":"051","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AM","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Aruba","alpha-2":"AW","alpha-3":"ABW","country-code":"533","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AW","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Australia","alpha-2":"AU","alpha-3":"AUS","country-code":"036","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AU","region-code":"009","sub-region-code":"053"},{"name":"Austria","alpha-2":"AT","alpha-3":"AUT","country-code":"040","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AT","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"155"},{"name":"Azerbaijan","alpha-2":"AZ","alpha-3":"AZE","country-code":"031","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:AZ","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Bahamas","alpha-2":"BS","alpha-3":"BHS","country-code":"044","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BS","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Bahrain","alpha-2":"BH","alpha-3":"BHR","country-code":"048","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BH","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Bangladesh","alpha-2":"BD","alpha-3":"BGD","country-code":"050","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BD","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"034"},{"name":"Barbados","alpha-2":"BB","alpha-3":"BRB","country-code":"052","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BB","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Belarus","alpha-2":"BY","alpha-3":"BLR","country-code":"112","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BY","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"151"},{"name":"Belgium","alpha-2":"BE","alpha-3":"BEL","country-code":"056","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BE","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"155"},{"name":"Belize","alpha-2":"BZ","alpha-3":"BLZ","country-code":"084","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BZ","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"013"},{"name":"Benin","alpha-2":"BJ","alpha-3":"BEN","country-code":"204","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BJ","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Bermuda","alpha-2":"BM","alpha-3":"BMU","country-code":"060","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BM","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"021"},{"name":"Bhutan","alpha-2":"BT","alpha-3":"BTN","country-code":"064","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BT","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"034"},{"name":"Bolivia, Plurinational State of","alpha-2":"BO","alpha-3":"BOL","country-code":"068","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BO","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba","alpha-2":"BQ","alpha-3":"BES","country-code":"535","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BQ","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","alpha-2":"BA","alpha-3":"BIH","country-code":"070","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BA","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Botswana","alpha-2":"BW","alpha-3":"BWA","country-code":"072","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BW","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"018"},{"name":"Bouvet Island","alpha-2":"BV","alpha-3":"BVT","country-code":"074","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BV"},{"name":"Brazil","alpha-2":"BR","alpha-3":"BRA","country-code":"076","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BR","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"British Indian Ocean Territory","alpha-2":"IO","alpha-3":"IOT","country-code":"086","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IO"},{"name":"Brunei Darussalam","alpha-2":"BN","alpha-3":"BRN","country-code":"096","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BN","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"035"},{"name":"Bulgaria","alpha-2":"BG","alpha-3":"BGR","country-code":"100","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BG","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"151"},{"name":"Burkina Faso","alpha-2":"BF","alpha-3":"BFA","country-code":"854","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BF","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Burundi","alpha-2":"BI","alpha-3":"BDI","country-code":"108","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:BI","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"014"},{"name":"Cambodia","alpha-2":"KH","alpha-3":"KHM","country-code":"116","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:KH","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"035"},{"name":"Cameroon","alpha-2":"CM","alpha-3":"CMR","country-code":"120","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CM","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Canada","alpha-2":"CA","alpha-3":"CAN","country-code":"124","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CA","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"021"},{"name":"Cape Verde","alpha-2":"CV","alpha-3":"CPV","country-code":"132","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CV","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Cayman Islands","alpha-2":"KY","alpha-3":"CYM","country-code":"136","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:KY","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Central African Republic","alpha-2":"CF","alpha-3":"CAF","country-code":"140","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CF","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Chad","alpha-2":"TD","alpha-3":"TCD","country-code":"148","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:TD","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Chile","alpha-2":"CL","alpha-3":"CHL","country-code":"152","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CL","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"China","alpha-2":"CN","alpha-3":"CHN","country-code":"156","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CN","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"030"},{"name":"Christmas Island","alpha-2":"CX","alpha-3":"CXR","country-code":"162","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CX"},{"name":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","alpha-2":"CC","alpha-3":"CCK","country-code":"166","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CC"},{"name":"Colombia","alpha-2":"CO","alpha-3":"COL","country-code":"170","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CO","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"Comoros","alpha-2":"KM","alpha-3":"COM","country-code":"174","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:KM","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"014"},{"name":"Congo","alpha-2":"CG","alpha-3":"COG","country-code":"178","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CG","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Congo, the Democratic Republic of the","alpha-2":"CD","alpha-3":"COD","country-code":"180","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CD","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Cook Islands","alpha-2":"CK","alpha-3":"COK","country-code":"184","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CK","region-code":"009","sub-region-code":"061"},{"name":"Costa Rica","alpha-2":"CR","alpha-3":"CRI","country-code":"188","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CR","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"013"},{"name":"Côte d'Ivoire","alpha-2":"CI","alpha-3":"CIV","country-code":"384","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CI","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Croatia","alpha-2":"HR","alpha-3":"HRV","country-code":"191","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:HR","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Cuba","alpha-2":"CU","alpha-3":"CUB","country-code":"192","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CU","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Curaçao","alpha-2":"CW","alpha-3":"CUW","country-code":"531","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CW","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Cyprus","alpha-2":"CY","alpha-3":"CYP","country-code":"196","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CY","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Czech Republic","alpha-2":"CZ","alpha-3":"CZE","country-code":"203","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:CZ","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"151"},{"name":"Denmark","alpha-2":"DK","alpha-3":"DNK","country-code":"208","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:DK","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Djibouti","alpha-2":"DJ","alpha-3":"DJI","country-code":"262","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:DJ","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"014"},{"name":"Dominica","alpha-2":"DM","alpha-3":"DMA","country-code":"212","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:DM","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Dominican Republic","alpha-2":"DO","alpha-3":"DOM","country-code":"214","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:DO","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Ecuador","alpha-2":"EC","alpha-3":"ECU","country-code":"218","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:EC","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"Egypt","alpha-2":"EG","alpha-3":"EGY","country-code":"818","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:EG","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"015"},{"name":"El Salvador","alpha-2":"SV","alpha-3":"SLV","country-code":"222","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:SV","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"013"},{"name":"Equatorial Guinea","alpha-2":"GQ","alpha-3":"GNQ","country-code":"226","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GQ","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Eritrea","alpha-2":"ER","alpha-3":"ERI","country-code":"232","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:ER","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"014"},{"name":"Estonia","alpha-2":"EE","alpha-3":"EST","country-code":"233","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:EE","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Ethiopia","alpha-2":"ET","alpha-3":"ETH","country-code":"231","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:ET","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"014"},{"name":"Falkland Islands (Malvinas)","alpha-2":"FK","alpha-3":"FLK","country-code":"238","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:FK","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"Faroe Islands","alpha-2":"FO","alpha-3":"FRO","country-code":"234","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:FO","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Fiji","alpha-2":"FJ","alpha-3":"FJI","country-code":"242","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:FJ","region-code":"009","sub-region-code":"054"},{"name":"Finland","alpha-2":"FI","alpha-3":"FIN","country-code":"246","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:FI","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"France","alpha-2":"FR","alpha-3":"FRA","country-code":"250","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:FR","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"155"},{"name":"French Guiana","alpha-2":"GF","alpha-3":"GUF","country-code":"254","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GF","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"French Polynesia","alpha-2":"PF","alpha-3":"PYF","country-code":"258","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:PF","region-code":"009","sub-region-code":"061"},{"name":"French Southern Territories","alpha-2":"TF","alpha-3":"ATF","country-code":"260","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:TF"},{"name":"Gabon","alpha-2":"GA","alpha-3":"GAB","country-code":"266","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GA","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"017"},{"name":"Gambia","alpha-2":"GM","alpha-3":"GMB","country-code":"270","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GM","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Georgia","alpha-2":"GE","alpha-3":"GEO","country-code":"268","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GE","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Germany","alpha-2":"DE","alpha-3":"DEU","country-code":"276","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:DE","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"155"},{"name":"Ghana","alpha-2":"GH","alpha-3":"GHA","country-code":"288","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GH","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Gibraltar","alpha-2":"GI","alpha-3":"GIB","country-code":"292","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GI","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Greece","alpha-2":"GR","alpha-3":"GRC","country-code":"300","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GR","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Greenland","alpha-2":"GL","alpha-3":"GRL","country-code":"304","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GL","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"021"},{"name":"Grenada","alpha-2":"GD","alpha-3":"GRD","country-code":"308","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GD","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Guadeloupe","alpha-2":"GP","alpha-3":"GLP","country-code":"312","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GP","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Guam","alpha-2":"GU","alpha-3":"GUM","country-code":"316","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GU","region-code":"009","sub-region-code":"057"},{"name":"Guatemala","alpha-2":"GT","alpha-3":"GTM","country-code":"320","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GT","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"013"},{"name":"Guernsey","alpha-2":"GG","alpha-3":"GGY","country-code":"831","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GG","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Guinea","alpha-2":"GN","alpha-3":"GIN","country-code":"324","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GN","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Guinea-Bissau","alpha-2":"GW","alpha-3":"GNB","country-code":"624","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GW","region-code":"002","sub-region-code":"011"},{"name":"Guyana","alpha-2":"GY","alpha-3":"GUY","country-code":"328","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:GY","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"005"},{"name":"Haiti","alpha-2":"HT","alpha-3":"HTI","country-code":"332","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:HT","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Heard Island and McDonald Islands","alpha-2":"HM","alpha-3":"HMD","country-code":"334","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:HM"},{"name":"Holy See (Vatican City State)","alpha-2":"VA","alpha-3":"VAT","country-code":"336","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:VA","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Honduras","alpha-2":"HN","alpha-3":"HND","country-code":"340","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:HN","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"013"},{"name":"Hong Kong","alpha-2":"HK","alpha-3":"HKG","country-code":"344","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:HK","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"030"},{"name":"Hungary","alpha-2":"HU","alpha-3":"HUN","country-code":"348","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:HU","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"151"},{"name":"Iceland","alpha-2":"IS","alpha-3":"ISL","country-code":"352","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IS","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"India","alpha-2":"IN","alpha-3":"IND","country-code":"356","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IN","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"034"},{"name":"Indonesia","alpha-2":"ID","alpha-3":"IDN","country-code":"360","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:ID","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"035"},{"name":"Iran, Islamic Republic of","alpha-2":"IR","alpha-3":"IRN","country-code":"364","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IR","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"034"},{"name":"Iraq","alpha-2":"IQ","alpha-3":"IRQ","country-code":"368","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IQ","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Ireland","alpha-2":"IE","alpha-3":"IRL","country-code":"372","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IE","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Isle of Man","alpha-2":"IM","alpha-3":"IMN","country-code":"833","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IM","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Israel","alpha-2":"IL","alpha-3":"ISR","country-code":"376","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IL","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Italy","alpha-2":"IT","alpha-3":"ITA","country-code":"380","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:IT","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"039"},{"name":"Jamaica","alpha-2":"JM","alpha-3":"JAM","country-code":"388","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:JM","region-code":"019","sub-region-code":"029"},{"name":"Japan","alpha-2":"JP","alpha-3":"JPN","country-code":"392","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:JP","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"030"},{"name":"Jersey","alpha-2":"JE","alpha-3":"JEY","country-code":"832","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:JE","region-code":"150","sub-region-code":"154"},{"name":"Jordan","alpha-2":"JO","alpha-3":"JOR","country-code":"400","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:JO","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"145"},{"name":"Kazakhstan","alpha-2":"KZ","alpha-3":"KAZ","country-code":"398","iso_3166-2":"ISO 3166-2:KZ","region-code":"142","sub-region-code":"143"}]
```

Comment: where do you want to get the country codes?

Comment: @ashok: Now I get the value of country is INDIA, but i want "IN" i.e 2character, for every countries.

Comment: @ashok_p: Are you there? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get content of .json file using PHP function

```
$content = file_get_contents('path_to_file');
```

then decode json format using `json_decode()` function.

hope this helps.

http://www.php.net/file_get_contents

http://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: Already i get the value of country INDIA(EXAMPLE) But i need "IN" for all countries. Please see my edited code

Comment: All countries or countries with name INDIA

Comment: According to customer entry. INDIA is just for example. i.e United states mean 'US' .. etc

Comment: After getting .json file content, you can check if Country_name present or not. If present replace that country name with "alpha-2" value.

Comment: That is my problem, I m new to php. This is first to create an app. can you help where to edit my code?

Comment: where do you want to get this country code??? i dont see any code related to country in your code.

Comment: Now i get the output as .csv file. I want the value of  shipping country as "alpha-2" value. still i got as like full name of country.